# how to insert Dependencies of bower with ASP.NET core

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-core, dependencies

I have this problem:

I wont use:

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js and https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js in a View.

So I downloaded from the 'Manage Packages Bower' the jquery-ui, but it does not work.

The console said: '$ is undefined' in the line..
I tried to put in the code:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

but without success, the same error.

how can I do?

Comment: Won't use, or will use?

Comment: "The console said: '$ is undefined' in the line" what line? can you provide more of your code?  where are you referencing $ in relation to your script includes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you specified the  lines BEFORE your scripts? Sorry I don't have enough rep to comment yet, otherwise I would have. But this is a popular problem for some people when they try to put their jquery code before they have included the jquery tags. Just a thought :)